# excel Formula to sum values in a column based on another value(txt) in any column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to write an `If` or `SumIf` to calculate(sum) totals for x , y and z individually.
I could use a simple sum formula but these are thousands of columns and x and y and z are populated randomly. I tried using a range by sorting colA but its a temporary solution and not what I am looking for.

I need something like:

```
If  COL A has 'X' then add values corresponding to X in COL B
```

example:

```
COLA   COLB  ....... colx
x      1         
x      2                
x      1
y      3
x      3
z      3
x      4
```

I tried looking up other answers for similar questions but could not find the right one that works for me.

Comment: Add a column to sum rows ColB to ColX, then use SUMIF() on that column and ColA

Comment: @pnuts - yes, the question is a little vague.

Comment: Did you find anything here useful? You did not post ant feedback,

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sum multiple columns based on a value in a single column you could use `SUMPRODUCT` like this

`=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A100="x")*B2:X100)`

There can't be text in the sum range, `B2:X100`, otherwise you get an error - if you want to allow text in that range use this version:

`=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A100="x")*ISNUMBER(B2:X100),B2:X100)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe (difficult to tell from the question):

```
=sumif(A:A,"=x",B:B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another answer could be that you create a pivot table of the database. Insert>Pivot Table>Select your table range. Then from there, you would put the column heading you wanted sorted into the row criteria, and then sum the x1's and y'1s.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to obtain subtotals for each column and each letter, as in the figure below.

If so, enter in B12 the formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$8=$A12)*(B$2:B$8))
```

Copy and paste into B12:C14. It is easy to adapt to slightly different arrangements.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I apologize if my question was vague. This is my first time working with `if` and `sumif` formulas in Excel.

This is what I was looking for: `=sumif(A:A,"=x",B:B)`.

Thank you Pnuts.

Comment: If this is what you found most useful, it is better that you accept pnuts' answer rather than posting another answer to acknowledge it. That is the way Stackoverflow works.