# COUNTIFS with ISNUMBER and multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, countif

I'm trying to count if the following range is `"Y"` or `"S"` and contains numbers. I'm trying to exclude cells beginning with `"_PVxxxxx_"`.

I cant use

```
COUNTIFS($A:$A,">0",$B:$B,"Y") + COUNTIFS($A:$A,">0",$B:$B,"S")
```

because the formula considers `"_PVxxxxx_"` to be more than `0` and includes them in the calculation.

Can anybody help? Thanks alot!

[image: Data Example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `SUMPRODUCT` is quite versatile, typically more flexible for testing than `COUNTIFS` and `SUMIFS`.

It should do the trick
(see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27935006/2707864 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/30854706/2707864)
with

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A:$A>0)*($B:$B="Y")*(ISNUMBER($A:$A))+...
```

This works, but I am not sure that you need the part `($A:$A>0)*` according to the sample you posted (it doesn't hurt anyway).

PS: If you insist on using `COUNTIFS` you could use a helper column that uses `ISNUMBER` and gives, e.g., a suitable numeric result (>0 for numeric data, <0 otherwise). Then you would refer to that column within `COUNTIFS`.

Comment: i have numbers such as 12345678 and PV1234. The problem is that the condition ">0" includes PV1234 into the calculation as well as it considers it to be > 0. I'm trying to calculate only pure numbers such as 12345678

Comment: this works, though, because ISNUMBER only works on numbers, probably best not to use whole columns with SUMPRODUCT though....

Comment: @kchungg - That is precisely the reason for using SUMPRODUCT, you can also test what you need. Plaease try the solution proposed and post feedback.

Comment: @barryhoudini - I most often restrict the ranges used in SUMPRODUCT. In this case, it is up to the OP knowing what he needs. At any rate, for the cases I dealt with, I never saw any impact on performance from using whole columns/rows.

Comment: @sancho.s Rather than having a `+` outside `SUMPRODUCT` to handle the "Y or S" condition, you can build this into one `SUMPRODUCT`. Replace `($B:$B="Y")` with `(($B:$B="Y")+($B:$B="S"))`. Otherwise I agree with your answer and gave you an up vote.

Comment: @asancho.s Sorry my comment was more directed at the OP, but especially if switching, as here, from `COUNTIFS` to `SUMPRODUCT` - the former will only calculate using the "used range"  when a full column is used - the latter will actually use the whole column

Comment: @sancho.s its working now. thank you so much! i went with the SUMPRODUCT solution as its more straight forward.